# Cast type T list to object

Tags: java, casting

I have a method which takes generic T type parameters.

```
public<T> void run(List<T> inputs){
 System.out.println((Student) inputs.get(0).getFirstName());

}
```

I am trying to access Student class methods inside run method.

But I am getting **cannot resolve method 'getFirstName()'** compilation error.

Please help!

Comment: If you are casting to a `Student` then it ain't generic.  BTW you are trying to cast the return value of `getFirstName` to a `Student`

Comment: Oh, yes just now I realized. I want to access methods of Student class. How can I do that?

Comment: your type casting is wrong. It should be ```((Student) inputs.get(0)).getFirstName()```

Comment: Also, you should be doing `<T extends Student>` - Almost always if you are casting, then you are doing it wrong

Comment: @siddarth- I tried that as well, still Student class methods are not accessible.

Comment: Please paste the compilation error. Your question is of very disturbing nature and you MUST be missing out on something futile.

Answer (score 0):

Your calling getFirstName() method with the wrong reference.please find below code.

Keep this type casting '(Student) inputs.get(0)' in ().

```
public<T> void run(List<T> inputs){
 System.out.println( ((Student) inputs.get(0)).getFirstName());

}
```

Comment: What happens if the `list` contains non `Student` objects?

Comment: You will get 'ClassCastException'.

Comment: What would happen if you had `<T extends Student>` ?

Comment: Whatever if List contains non-Student objects definitely you will get  'ClassCastException'.

Comment: You can avoid ClassCastException by checking reference using 'instanceof'                if(Student instanceof inputs.get(0)) {  // write you logic here }